# Jquery DataTable keeps going back to first page when changing the checked status of checkboxes in other pages with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following code

```
    $('input[name="select-all"]').click(function() {
     //channel-data is initialised as DataTable
     $('#channel-table').find('input[name="batch-select"]:checked').each(function () {
        $(this).prop("checked",true);
    });
});
```

whenever I click the select all button in any page other than 1st The datatable keeps reverting back to the first page.
I  think it happens because of redraw due to change in checkboxes property.Any work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, probably - but have not seen any reason for test your hypothesis :) When dealing with dataTables, **always** go through the API! There is a neat [**`every()`**](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()) method you can use to cycle through all rows and update a checkbox as checked. Here is an example, have tried to reproduce your setup with a "select all" button and checkboxes :

```
$('input[name="select-all"]').click(function() {
  table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) {
     var $tr = this.nodes().to$()
     $tr.find('input[name="batch-select"]').prop('checked', true)
   })     
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/u9Lq56v1/**

- does not change page
- does actually update checkboxes also on hidden pages (that would the code in OP fail as well)

Comment: i want to change the rows on current page only

Comment: @rahultyagi - Use `rows({ page: 'current' })` if you just want to target the checkboxes on the current page. See updated demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/u9Lq56v1/1/**

Comment: Somehow when i use the code on my project it keeps going back to first page

Comment: Hey @rahultyagi, it sounds strange. You do not have any other triggers or event handlers that might reload data, refresh the table or similar..?

Comment: yeah The select all button i m using is located in the <th> of table so maybe thats trigeering redraw i wil try chaning it

Comment: @rahultyagi, YES -thats it! Easy to reproduce, you can avoid this by `e.stopPropagation` and a final `return false`, see updated demo with `<input>` in the `<th>` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/u9Lq56v1/2/**

Comment: you are the best person i ever met here

Comment: e.stopPropogation() does not actually work but thanks thats all teh help i needed i wil just move the select all outside of table :)

Comment: Disabling sorting on the `th` with the select All button is what is required to get it to stay on the current page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41950108/check-all-checkboxes-on-the-current-page-only-in-datatables This is because it defaults to sorting by the CB value