# Check all checkboxes on the current page only in datatables

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, datatables

I need a solution for this. Here is what I am trying to do. I have a datatable that has some values and check boxes in the first columns. What I need is when I select the check box in the header it should select all the values in the current page only. But all the check boxes of all the pages get selected.

I also want that, When I navigate to another page of the datatable, the check box selections of all the previous page should be unchecked including the check box in the header.

Hear is my code:

```
<?php if($acl->can('view_article')){ ?> 
<table id="articles" class="table table-striped table-bordered"        cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <?php if($acl->can('delete_article')){ ?>
        <th><input id="select_all_existent" type="checkbox" /></th>
        <?php } ?>
        <th>Article</th>
        <th>Categories</th>
        <th>Demographic</th>
        <th>Intended Month</th>
        <th class="text-right">Word Count</th>


    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php
    foreach($articles as $article) {
        $id =                   $article["id"];
        $uid =                  $article["uid"];
        $article_name =         $article["article_name"];
        $article_file_path =    $article["article_file_path"];
        $article_category =     $article["article_category"];
        $article_demographic =  $article["article_demographic"];
        $article_word_count =   $article["article_word_count"];
        $intended_month =        $article["intended_month"];
        $article_created    =   $article["article_created"];
        if(!empty($article_demographic)) {
            $article_demographic = implode(", ",$article_demographic);
        }
        $article_keywords =     $article["article_keywords"];
        $article_description =  $article["article_description"];
        $checkbox =  in_array($id, $assigned_articles)? " ":"<input type='checkbox' value=".$id." />";

        echo "
            <tr class='' data-id='$id'>
                " ;
                if($acl->can('delete_article'))
                echo "<td>$checkbox</td>";

                if($acl->can('edit_article')){
                echo "<td>" . anchor("articles/edit/$id",$article_name.'- '.$article_word_count,"class='notBtn' title=\"$article_description\"") . " </td>";
                }else{
                echo "<td>$article_name - $article_word_count</td>";    
                }


        echo "
                <td>".short_string($article_category)."</td>
                <td>".short_string($article_demographic)."</td>
                <td> $intended_month </td>
                <td align='right'>$article_word_count</td>

            </tr>";
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
</table>
<?php } ?>
<script type="application/javascript">

    $(document).on( 'init', function ( e, settings ) {
        alert( 'Saved page length is: '+ table.state().length );
    } );

$(document).ready(function(){

    var oTable = $("#articles").DataTable({
        "stateSave": true,
         "order": [],
        "dom": '<"row" <"col-md-12 space" <"datatable-action pull-left"> <"datatable-n pull-right" l > > >rt <"row" <"col-md-6"  i > <"col-md-6" p > >',
        "columns" : [
                     <?php if($acl->can('delete_article')){ ?>
                    {orderable: false, searchable: false},
                    <?php } ?>
                    {"width": "25%" },
                    null,
                    null,
                    {"width": "12%" },
                    {"width": "10%" },

                                          ],

        "fnDrawCallback": function( oSettings ) {


            $('.popupArticle').viewArticle({
                url : '<?=site_url("articles/showArticleInPopup");?>',
                title : 'Article Preview',
                size : 'lg'
            });

            }                                             

    });

    $('#search-inp').on('keyup',function(){
          oTable.search($(this).val()).draw() ;
    })

    if(oTable.state().length != 0)
    $('#search-inp').val(oTable.state().search.search);

    checkAllCheckbox(oTable);

    var deletebtn = '';
    <?php if($acl->can('delete_article')){ ?>
    var deletebtn = '<a href="delete" id="deletebtn" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete Articles" data-title="Delete Articles" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>';
    <?php } ?>

    var assignbtn = '';
     <?php if($acl->can('assign_article')){ ?>
    var assignbtn = '<a href="#" id="assignbtn" title="Assign Articles"  class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#assignArticlePopup"><i  class="fa fa-paperclip"></i></a>';
    <?php } ?>
       $("div.datatable-action").html(deletebtn + ' ' +assignbtn);


    $('#assignbtn').on('click', function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
      eModal.setEModalOptions({loadingHtml : ''});
      eModal.iframe('<?= site_url("assignArticles/e/"); ?>', 'Assign  Article').then(function (input) {
$('.modal-dialog', window.document).css('width', '80%');

if ($('.modal-footer', window.document).length == 0) {
    $('.modal-content', window.document).append('<div class="modal-footer">  </div>');
}


  });

});  

});

</script>
```

Here is the code for checkAllCheckbox(oTable);

```
function checkAllCheckbox(oTable) {

/* Check all in Datatable*/

if ($("#select_all_existent").length != 0) {

    var cells = oTable.cells().nodes();

    $("#select_all_existent").change(function () {
        $(cells).find(":checkbox").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
    });

    $(cells).find(":checkbox").change(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(":checked")){
            $("#select_all_existent").prop("checked",  $(this).is(":checked"));
        }
        else{
             if ($(cells).find(":checkbox").length ==  $(cells).find(":checked").length) {
               $("#select_all_existent").prop("checked",true);
             }               
        }

      if ($(cells).find(":checked").length > 0) {
           $(oTable.table().container()).siblings().find('.help- block').html('');
      }  
      else{

          $(oTable.table().container()).siblings().find('.help- block').html('Please select at least one checkbox');  
      } 

    });


}

}
```

Any help on the scenarios that I have mentioned would be appreciated.

Comment: Try writing code for visible elements, in your scenario, I hope I m clear

Comment: @rahul_m Visible HTML elements?

Comment: Yes, if I am not wrong, you're doing pagination, with check single and check all functionality, So, you can check like, only which are visible should be checked

Comment: Yes, this is pagination. I am trying to work a similar functionality that gmail or other web apps do. Select only the check boxes on the current page. My requirement also is to uncheck all the selection when the user navigates back to the previous page. I hop you understand. Meanwhile I am trying to apply the visibility check as you have mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code made the following changes and try:

change 1: disable sorting of checkbox column

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <?php if($acl->can('delete_article')){ ?>
    <th data-orderable="false"><input id="select_all_existent" type="checkbox" /></th>
    <?php } ?>
    <th>Article</th>
    <th>Categories</th>
    <th>Demographic</th>
    <th>Intended Month</th>
    <th class="text-right">Word Count</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

change 2:

add the following code to script:

```
    $('#articles').on('page.dt', function() {
        $('#select_all_existent').prop("checked", 0);
        $('#select_all_existent').trigger('change');
    });

    $('#articles').on('length.dt', function() {
        $('#select_all_existent').prop("checked", 0);
        $('#select_all_existent').trigger('change');
    });


    $('#select_all_existent').on('change',function () {
       checkAllCheckbox(oTable);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @mith This was exactly what I was looking for. Can you please explain as to why we need to disable the sorting of the check box column in order to achieve this? Thanks for the help

Comment: if sorting of check box column enabled, on clicking the checkbox from other pages (2,3, etc) it will go to first page because of sorting.